# Rails ActiveJob with Sleep Function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a function that scrapes a site with a delay between page loads. Using sleep in the function causes rails to freeze up until this is finished.

How should I go about having a delay between page loads in a job?

Comment: ActiveJob allows scheduling jobs in the future. You'll need an external job processor for this, though. (sidekiq, for example)

Answer (score 0):

In development you will have a single process running, and so when you start the scraping procedure the system process will be occupied with this and unable to respond to any other requests. i.e. blocking

For this to work more as you might want, run the scraping task in a separate process (as Sergio suggested) using an async ActiveJob backend. Unless you have reason, probably choose DelayedJob, as this uses an Active Record database (which you are probably already using), or for starters in development use the built in async adaptor.

```
class ScrapeJob < ApplicationJob
  self.queue_adapter = :async

  def perform(url)
    # do scraping
  end
end

ScrapeJob.perform_later(url)
```

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters.html

Also, with regard your delay time,you could create a delay of say 10x the response time of the previous request. Or a minimum of 1 second, whichever is bigger.

```
require 'benchmark'

urls.each do |url|
  time = Benchmark.measure do
    # scrape page
  end

  sleep(time.realtime * 10)
end
```